# Automatic grid movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to know how can I modify my code for my enemy to be able to move automatically in my grid ?

This is my code below :

[using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

```
private float moveSpeed = 50f;
private float gridSize = 18f;
private enum Orientation {
    Horizontal,
    Vertical
};
private Orientation gridOrientation = Orientation.Vertical;
private bool allowDiagonals = false;
private bool correctDiagonalSpeed = true;
private Vector2 input;
private bool isMoving = false;
private Vector3 startPosition;
private Vector3 endPosition;
private float t;
private float factor;

public void Update() {
    if (!isMoving) {
        input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        if (!allowDiagonals) {
            if (Mathf.Abs(input.x) > Mathf.Abs(input.y)) {
                input.y = 0;
            } else {
                input.x = 0;
            }
        }

        if (input != Vector2.zero) {
            StartCoroutine(move(transform));
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerator move (Transform transform)
{
    isMoving = true;
    startPosition = transform.position;
    t = 0;

    if (gridOrientation == Orientation.Horizontal) {
        endPosition = new Vector3 (startPosition.x + System.Math.Sign (input.x) * gridSize,
            startPosition.y, startPosition.z + System.Math.Sign (input.y) * gridSize);
    } else {
        endPosition = new Vector3 (startPosition.x + System.Math.Sign (input.x) * gridSize,
            startPosition.y + System.Math.Sign (input.y) * gridSize, startPosition.z);
    }

    if (allowDiagonals && correctDiagonalSpeed && input.x != 0 && input.y != 0) {
        factor = 0.7071f;
    } else {
        factor = 1f;
    }

    while (t < 1f) {
        t += Time.deltaTime * (moveSpeed / gridSize) * factor;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (startPosition, endPosition, t);
        yield return null;
    }

    isMoving = false;
    yield return 0;
}
```

}
]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "automatically"? What have you already attempted to achieve this, and how have you been unsuccessful?

Comment: I mean something like a pathfinding , the Enemy will go back and forth in an certain  Axis or more !

Comment: What is "something like pathfinding"? What does not work? Do not ignore Serlite asking you to tell us what you tried so far and how it failed. Right now, I see some random snippet of code and have no idea what you want from us.

Comment: The correct answer to this question as it's written currently, is "Research" This seems like what you are asking for is some simple AI solution.  Here, to get you started [Simple AI for 2D grid based game](https://www.gamedev.net/topic/619195-simple-ai-for-2d-grid-based-game/)